# Google Sheets to recognize bank movements in a cell according to a list of words

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet where every month I copy from my bank website the movements and paste them in a sheet, then according to a list of words (which I write in a column on the sheet) I have a formula that will recognize the movements and categorize them.

I made an example sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cUf3y2sfr9iSAt5SLIhVmoAD9qjdrxu-_qkcex1Isx8/edit#gid=1620937687)

The Formula I have at this moment is working more or less correctly (it misses some movements and only consider one word to search), and but is very slow. Every month I have quite a movements, and the sheet has all 12 months of the year, every time I paste the movements of a month it takes a while for it to process it all

- So, is it possible to have a better/faster more accurate formula than the one I have in column E?
- And, would it be possible to have a formula that will search/recognize the movements according to 2 words (and not just 1 word like my actual formula)?
  In some real cases, 2 words to recognize would be much better

Thanks in advance for any help/advice.

Answer (score 0):

**cell E1:**

```
=IFERROR(QUERY({FILTER(I2:I;I2:I<>"")\FILTER(K2:K; K2:K<>"")}; 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''"; 0); 
 "add allias")
```

**cell J1:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY({PROPER(A2:A)\B2:B}; 
 "select * where Col1 is not null"; 0); 
 "select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"; 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi player0 , thanks for the help, your formula seems great, more recent and faster. 

Altought for my purposes is not good for this, using your formula i need to categorize individually every row/movement and i pretend to have a list of words (collumn J ) for the formula search in collumn A and auto categorize them. The rows it cant find, i will categorize mannualy.

I have updated my sheet with real examples, so i hope you can better understand what i´m trying to explain

Sorry for asking but i hope you can help.

Comment: not sure if you understood my proposal... with it all you need to do is type in aliases in J column and all of it shall be distributed and calculated accordingly

Comment: I understand your formula (although i could never do it from scratch) . 

The problem using your formula is i would have to every month categorize every row (mannualy write the "alias").

It would be much easier to have 1 list of words (that would be useful for all months) that the formula recognize inside the cell (bank movement) and auto categorize it (most results anyway), like it happens in my current formula (only its slow and a little "dumb"). Your formula is great but obliges me to categorize every row, every month.

I updated the sheet with real examples, i hope you understand me